# Radare2 "dc" and "dce" command pausing

Tags: buffer-overflow, fuzzing, radare2

I am working on learning Radare2 for fuzzing\vulnerability research and I've found that the commands 'dc' and 'dce' aren't working the way I expect them to.
I run the command

```
radare2 -A -d <path_to>BlazeHDTV.exe
```

It does its magic and I'm at the entry of the exe.
Next i run the commands either 'dc'[continue execution of all children] or 'dce'[continue execution(pass exception to program)]
the commands run and  execution pauses after a few lines of calling load library.

```
[0x77183260]> dce
r_w32_dbg_modules/CreateToolhelp32Snapshot: Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory 
request was completed.
(744) loading library at 0000000077150000 (C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll) ntdll.dll
r_w32_dbg_modules/CreateToolhelp32Snapshot: Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory 
request was completed.
(744) loading library at 0000000077330000 (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll) ntdll.dll
r_w32_dbg_modules/CreateToolhelp32Snapshot: Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory 
request was completed.
(744) loading library at 0000000073940000 (C:\Windows\System32\wow64.dll) wow64.dll
(744) loading library at 00000000738E0000 (C:\Windows\System32\wow64win.dll) wow64win.dll
(744) loading library at 00000000738D0000 (C:\Windows\System32\wow64cpu.dll) wow64cpu.dll
[0x77201221]>
```

Now if i repeat the command again a few times the program gets to be running in the background and i can do what ever fuzzing or VR i am trying to do but is there anyway i can just get this to go without having type in 'dc' 3 or 4 times in a row?